# ListView is not displaying the data feed to it

Tags: android

I was trying a simple app and when I feed values to list view it does not display naything.

Snapshot of my problem:

[image]

My Activitymain xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seek1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivty.java file:

```
package me.mukundmadhav.timestable;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);

    seekBar.setMax(20);
    seekBar.setProgress(1);



    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
            {
                Log.i(Integer.toString(progress),Integer.toString(progress * i));
            }




    }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    ArrayList<String> table = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=10;++i){
        table.add("a");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> tableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, table);
    listView.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
}
}
```

I tried commenting out segments of code but still wasn't able to fix my problem.

Comment: Not related to your issue: Start using RecyclerView. It's the future. ListView is a thing of past. RecyclerView comes with infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its seems your text is being visible. Its just white in color. To change the text color, if you don't want to change your primary text color, create a new layout which has a text view as follow


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now save the file as row_item_list.xml.

Now replace

```
ArrayAdapter<String> tableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, table);
```

with

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> tableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_item_list, table);
```

Answer (score 0):

text.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now in activity file:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> tableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, table);
listView.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
 ........
 ArrayAdapter<String> tableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, table){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            return textView;
        }

 };
 listView.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
 .......
```